# The shortest connection algorithm, mind game

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, routes

This is a question from a mind games book. I tried solving it like this (http://pastebin.com/sdfcuxW1) but had no luck. It also has to be very optimized to process outputs for 2000 input coordinates under 4 seconds.

Any suggestions about my code, or any new algorithm ideas would be very helpful.

**Question:**
We have a coordinate plane, and we are only using the first quadrant. We are supplied with a number of coordinates each with +X and +Y values. For example 0,2 - 5,4 etc. We are required to connect each of these coordinates with rectangles (one corner of the rectangle touches one coordinate and another corner touches another coordinate) so that all coordinates are in contact with each other (no left-outs). We also have to make sure that the rectangles that we use to connect our 2 coordinates do not overlap with any other coordinate (on the edges is fine). What kind of algorithm can print out the best solution to this problem, given that the goal is to use the smallest total rectangle area possible.

http://cl.ly/image/1P012s3p1E1g
purple areas are rectangles and green dots are coordinates. we can have rectangles which have 0 height of width, which consume no area.

What I couldn't figure out: find the closest coordinates to our starting coordinate is easy. but it is hard to make sure that all coordinates are connected together. i always get pieces of coordinates floating in different areas of the plane. my code also lags with >1000 points.

Comment: I did not see your code, but i would suggest you that what you are trying to do is given a list of points, you are linking each other with rectangles and using the smallest total area. So i would get the list of points then for each point find the closest one ( diatnce between two points a and b is `d=sqrt((xa-xb)²+(ya-yb)²)` ) then make a rectangle out of this two points. That should do the work, the only issue is that sometimes it will print two identical rectangles but that's not really an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

1. Let's model this problem as a graph problem.
2. The vertices are the given points.
3. There is an edge between every pair vertices. The weight of this edge is the area of the rectangle formed by this pair of points.
4. The answer is the minimum spanning tree in this graph. We can use Prim's algorithm to find it.

The time complexity of this solution is `O(n ^ 2)`.

The only question is: why can't a rectangle generated by this algorithm contain another point? I will not post a formal proof here, but drawing some pictures shows that if there is such a rectangle, the solution is not optimal(an idea of a proof: let's assume that there is a point inside. We can split this rectangle into two so that this points becomes one of their corner. The total area can only decrease after performing this operation).